# How can I add Automatic intellisense to a Textbox using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to add automatic Intellisense (Auto Complete--Filtering Search Result) to a textbox, corresponding to the words that I'm typing in that textbox and the Intellisense is fetched from a database table. How can I achieve this? Can anyone help?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#city').autocomplete({
       source:'send.php'
    });
});
```

send.php file given below:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","hari","123","hari");
    
$searchTerm = $_GET['query'];  //get search term
    

$query = $db->query("SELECT fname FROM user WHERE fname LIKE 
         '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY fname ASC");  //get matched data from user table

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['fname'];
}
        
echo json_encode($data);//return json data
```

Corresponding HTML Code is given below:

```
<div class="content col-sm-12">
   <form>
      <h1>Hello!!!</h1>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="20" class="city" 
             placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code"><br><br>    
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the following scripts in your html page

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

And add the following css in head of your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

The mistake you made is the parameter passing with the name `term` and trying to read with the name `query` in your php file. In your send.php file change the line

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['query'];
```

into

```
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#city').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                      $.ajax( {
                               url: "send.php",
                               dataType: "jsonp",
                               data: {
                                    query: request.term
                               },
                              success: function( data ) {
                                   response( data );
                              }
                      } );
                    },

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a recommendation for you, use angular 1 for this, you can simply write that code without additional UI libraries and with much much better performance and issue-free solution.

1. Add the following parent div to your input element:
2. Change your input to this:

`<input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="20" class="city" ng-model="query" ng-change="fetch()" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">`

3. Add the following code right under your `<input>`:

   `<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="text in suggestions">{{ text }}</li>
   </ul>`
4. As a basic set up, you need this in your `<head>` section:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>`

5. Finally you will create a new file like in assets directory like "suggestions.js" in your assets directory or somewhere and add this file right before you your `</body>` tag like this in your template:

`<script src="assets/suggestions.js"></script>`

The file will have the following lines:

```html
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('suggestionsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.suggestions = [];
        $scope.query = '';

        $scope.fetch = function() {
          $http({method: 'POST', url: 'send.php', params: { query: $scope.query } }).
            then(function(response) {

              $scope.status = response.status;
              $scope.suggestions = response.data;

            }, function(response) {
                /* SOMETHING WENT WRONG WTIH THE CALL DO SOMETHING HERE */
          });
        };

    });
```

There is very simple set-up/tutorial for Angular 1 here:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

**This is not a direct answer but believe me a more efficient answer. Angular 1 and the newer versions save a lot of time and brings performance.**

And btw, autocomplete() is not a native jQuery function. Also I do not mention that you need jQuery also for Angular, but I assume it's already added in your template.